# If statement does not find value in List in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I use this if-statement:

```
if(category.id!='0') {
  return CategoryWidget(category: category);
}
```

Why does it not give true back and returns the widget when I use this command to add an item to the list?

```
_categories.insert(0, categoryAll);
```

When I add an item in the list using this command everything works fine. But I need the insert to put the added item on the beginning because of sorting the list.

```
_categories.add(categoryAll);
```

with insert command:

[image: with insert command]

with add command:

[image: with add command]

Comment: Suppose you have to insert item of id 0 use  if(category.id=='0') {
  return CategoryWidget(category: category);
}

Comment: What do you mean? The add or insert the item works in both ways. Only the if statement does not work when I inserted instead of added. See also images I put to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem in your code isn't about using the `insert` or `add` but not returning a widget in your ListView builder:

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: categories.length,
  ...
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final category = categories[index];
    if(category.id!='0') {
      return CategoryWidget(category: category);
    }
    // Error here, you didn't return any widget if category.id == '0'
  },
)
```

You need to fix your code to something like this:

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: categories.length,
  ...
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final category = categories[index];
    if(category.id =='0') {
      // return your default widget or specific widget here
      return DefaultCategoryWidget();
    } else {
      return CategoryWidget(category: category);
    }
    
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. I changed my code to this and it works now.

```
if(category.id!='0') {
  return CategoryWidget(category: category);
  } else {
  return Container();
}
```